# Google maps add marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to add marker to Google map in android can any one please help me to do it and if you guys have sample code it would help me a lot, and also tell me that how can i set size to map fragment ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run map samples from google play services library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `addMarker()`

like :

```
myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(yourLatLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.yourmarkericon)));
```

where **myMap** is the Object of `GoogleMap` and **yourLatlng** is `Latlng` Where you want to add marker and **yourmarkericon** is icon which you want to display on map

**Edit :**

**References**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker

**Simple Tutorial**

http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html

Comment: @Ihsanchahi see updated answer, i have provided the References