# Add marker using Lat/Lng when Google Map loads

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to know
if we can add marker in Google Maps using longitude and latitude provided from firebase database. When maps fragment is loaded.
In simple I want to add markers in Google Maps using my own longitude and latitude and it should mark all the places say if I have 10 place's lng and lat.
Now I want to show all 10 places on Google Maps and some additional information also

Comment: It is definitely possible to add you own markers.  Just Google around or search SO and you will find examples.

Comment: Pleace include some of your code next time you ask a question. Asking for full solutions or for how to google, is not what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: Just look up [this repo](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo) The things you mentioned are basic things, you can see examples anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps add marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638584/google-maps-add-marker)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Ther is a function `addMarker()` on `map` object to do that:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Hello world"));
}
```

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker